# How do I spoof camera input by using a pre-recorded video instead?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, video, video-recording

We need to joke a friend and we can't figure out how to do this. It should be applicable to any app that requests a video feed

Comment: You'd need to find or make a custom ROM that supports this.

Comment: @DanHulme Easier: Write an Xposed module and hook the related APIs.

Comment: @iBug I have Xposed Module but have no idea how to achieve this with that. Or I'm just searching for the wrong terms on Google